# Confusion about the definition of positive definiteness

Tags: linear-algebra, definition, inner-products, positive-definite

First let me check my definition is correct:

- Let $A\in M_n(\Bbb C)$. If $(\forall x\in\Bbb C^n\setminus\{0\},~x^*Ax>0)$, then we called $A$ positive definite.
- Let $A\in M_n(\Bbb R)$. If $(\forall x\in\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\},~x^TAx>0)$, then we called $A$ positive definite.

First question: is my definition stated above "correct" (namely, standard)?

Second, now, if $A=\begin{bmatrix}2&3\\
1&4\end{bmatrix}$. By the second meaning/definition of positive definite, it really is positive definite. However, how about in view of the first definition? $A$ is not Hermitian, hence it is impossible that $(\forall x\in\Bbb C^n\setminus\{0\},~x^*Ax>0)$. Then shouldn't $A$ be non positive definite?

Third, if $A\in M_n(\Bbb R)$ is real, symmetric. Then does "$\forall x\in\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\},~x^TAx>0$" necessarily implies "$\forall x\in\Bbb C^n\setminus\{0\},~x^*Ax>0$"?

Comment: Did you compare with the [definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix)? There are examples given, too.

Comment: A **symmetric** matrix is called positive definite if ...Your $A$ is not symmetric.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Actually for a real symmetric matrix, I have heard people say that putting the requirement of being symmtric is not necessary. Since they can always be transfered to each other in some sense.

Comment: While it is not universal, it is very common to require the matrix be symmetric (or Hermitian in the complex case) in the definition of positive (semi-)definite.

Comment: If $A\in M_n(\Bbb R)$ is real, symmetric. Then does "$\forall x\in\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\},~x^TAx>0$" necessarily implies "$\forall x\in\Bbb C^n\setminus\{0\},~x^*Ax>0$"?

Comment: Yes, one only needs to show that $x^*Ax$ then is a real number. Then it follows.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Well.. I can't quite figure out the proof. Suppose $A$ is real symmetric and $\forall x\in\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\},~x^TAx>0$. Then $A$ is of course Hermitian, and hence $\forall x\in\Bbb C^n\setminus\{0\},~x^*Ax\in\Bbb R$. If $x\in\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$, then we already have $x^*Ax=x^TAx>0$. However, how to show when $x\in\Bbb C^n\setminus(\Bbb R^n\cup\{0\})$, $x^*Ax$ must also greater than $0$?

Comment: @Eric Write $z\in\mathbb C^n$ as $z=x+iy$, where $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$.  Then expand $z^*Az$, remembering that $(iy)^*Ax=-i(y^TAx)=-i(x^TAy)$.

Comment: Get it. It's not so trivial as I first guess, but it also turn out to be not very diffcult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A positive definite matrix is a Hermitian matrix which satisfies the condition that you described (the first one). Therefore, your matrix $A$ is *not* definite positive. However, note that where you wrote $x\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, you should have written $x\in\mathbb{C}^n\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Edited that typo. To the first question, so how should I say about $A$? $A$ is positive definite under the second meaning, and you said $A$ is not positive definite (under the first).

Comment: @Eric No; your matrix $A$ is **not** definite positive for *any* definition.